# Student Results Management System in C++, expression must have pointer to object type

Tags: c++, arrays, object, expression

I was wondering if someone could help me fix this. I am looking to grab the lowest score in a student management results analysis project in C++. I am getting a "expression must have pointer to object type" error. I have no idea how to fix this

```
struct candidate
{
    int candidates;
    char forename[20], surname[20];
    int area[5];
    double avg;
    public:
    void getdata();
    string calculateGrade();
    void showdata() const;
};

//Prints out the lowest mark

void lowestmark(double avg[])
{
    candidate st;
    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("student.dat", ios::binary);
    if (!inFile)
    {
        cout << "File could not be open! Press any Key...";
        cin.ignore();
        cin.get();
        return;
    }

    while (inFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char *> (&st), sizeof(candidate)))
    {
        double smallest = st.avg;

        // Loop to determine lowest score
        for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(candidate); i++)
        {
            if (smallest > st.avg[i])
            {
                smallest = st.avg[i];
                smallest = i;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `st.avg` is a `double`, it is not an array of `double`s. Hence, you can't use `st.avg[i]`.

Comment: Your whole for loop is wrong.  `st.avg` is not an array.

Comment: *inFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char *> (&st), sizeof(candidate)* -- Note that this will no longer work if you change `candidate` to have a member that is a non-POD type, such as `std::string`.

Comment: Off topic fun fact: In a `struct` everything is `public` unless otherwise specified.

Comment: Off topic:  Prefer to use `std::string` for text rather than character arrays.  Character arrays can easily suffer from buffer overrun.

Comment: BTW, the compiler is allowed to add *padding bytes* between members of a `struct` or `class`.

Comment: Your `for` loop won't work correctly because the limit of the loop is the *size of the entire structure, student names and all*.  You should set a constant for the capacity of the `area` member and use that constant in your loop.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an array to find the smallest average score:

```
double smallest_average = 100000.0;
candidate st;
while (infile.read((unsigned char *) &st, sizeof(st)))
{
  const double average_read = st.avg;
  if (average_read < smallest_average)
  {
    smallest_average = average_read;
  }
}
```

The search does not require all items stored into memory; only the current item read from the file.